# What is the explanation of this interesting property of twin primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, twin-primes

Let $(p, p+2)$ denote a pair of [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime) for $p > 3$. Consider a triplet $(2, 5, p)$ and consider a combination in which we take product of any two of these and add third to it. Thus, we get following three combinations: $2p + 5$, $5p+2$ and $p+10$. Out of curiosity, I tried to see the number of primes I get as I vary $p$. If we take any prime $p$ other than the first member of a twin prime pair, then we see that all three, exactly two, exactly one or none could be primes. For example, take $p = 7$ and you would find that all three combinations yield prime numbers.

Surprisingly, when $p$ is the first member of a twin prime pair other than $(3, 5)$, none of these combinations seems to be primes. This is not at all obvious to me. To be precise, I checked this for all twin primes less than a billion ($10^9$). Thus, numerical evidence does suggest that these combinations are always composites. Is there any way to prove this? Thank you

P.S. I can make the codes available to anybody interested, however this is a rather lengthy calculation (on an actual 32 core machine it took 2 hours excluding the time needed to generate these primes!).

Comment: Wouldn't "all three, exactly two, exactly one or none" exhaust **all** the possibilities? What is then so *special*, or whatever you're trying to convey, with taking the second number in a twin pair??

Comment: @DonAntonio: Well, in some sense nothing. But this particular property seems to hold only when $p$ is the first member of the twin prime pair and so I had to refer to "twin primes".

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar How can you say it **only** holds for twin primes when you clearly have found other non-twin primes where none of $2p+5,5p+2,p+10$ is prime.  That sounds a lot like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias

Comment: @Sn Thanks. So then the special feature here is that with the second element in a twin prime we *never* seem to get any prime, right?

Comment: @ErickWong : As I said, this happens only for the **first** member of the twin prime pair. When I said only, I meant that this doesn't happen for the second member of the twin prime pair.

Comment: @DonAntonio : No! For second member of the pair, anything can happen. All three could be primes, none could be primes etc. For the first member though, **all** the combinations are always composites!

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar What about for $23$?  $23$ is not the first member of a twin prime pair.  In what sense can you justify saying this pattern *only* occurs for twin primes?

Comment: @ErickWong : I just now edited my comment. I was referring to the twin prime pair. So more precisely, **only** refers to the first member of the twin prime pair. I meant it doesn't happen for the second member. Of course you could find primes which are not members of twin pair and for which something like this may happen.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Just three minutes ago you boldly exclaimed to DonAntonio that *anything could happen" for the second member.  Now you're saying that the "none are primes" case "doesn't happen" for the second member.  Again it is impossible for you to justify the word "only": you are ignoring the exceptions due to confirmation bias.

Comment: @ErickWong : Dear Erick, I would be happy to hear a nicer language on this site :) Did you read my question carefully? "None are primes" case is not a feature of the second member. That may or may not happen. For first member that always happens! Cheers!

Comment: If I have well understood the question, the answer is that we cannot have $p\geq 5$ congruent to $1$ moodulo $3$; otherwise, $p+2$ is divisible by $3$, hence not a prime. Now as $p$ must be congruent to $-1$ modulo $3$,  $2p+5,5p+2,p+10$ are all divisible by $3$, hence not prime.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Okay, I'll get directly to the point :).  The sentence "$n$ is the first member of a twin prime other than $(3,5)$" immediately implies "$n$ is congruent to $5$ mod $6$".  My very strong suspicion is that you have prematurely narrowed your consideration to the first property when you should be looking at the second.  This is precisely the fallacy of confirmation bias, which is a perfectly human foible.

Comment: @Kelenner : Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the expressions mod $3$. If $p$ and $p+2$ are each prime, then $p$ cannot be $1$ mod $3$, so must be $2$ mod $3$. But then each of the three expressions $2p+5, 5p+2, p+10$ are divisible by $3$.

Comment: Beat me by 2 seconds. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio And looking at the comments thread, it seems like Kelenner beat *me* by a full minute! (I didn't see their comment at the time of my answer.)